# release folder used by IIS in c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, directory, operating-system, rename

I don't know if my problem have a solution, but I would to try.
My project have an input type file where I can upload an image and place it in folder img in wwwroot folder.
I created my view in this way
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZMj8.png)
whereas in controller I wrote like this:

```
string wwwRootPath = varhostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
//path where I would put image
string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath, "img");
string completeFilePathImage = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder,model.Image.FileName);
model.Image.CopyTo(new FileStream(completeFilePathImage,FileMode.Create)); here
```

The problem is that, seems folder is locked by IIS till it is run. So I can't rename or delete files in img folder. Is there a way to lock the folder when I create a new file and release the folder after create?

thanks in advice for your responses

Comment: When is it locked by IIS?  Only when IIS is writing?

Comment: I don't think you can. But if you make your methods static, you can add another static variable and a static object. Then before your write lock the static object and check the value of the static variable.  That will tell you if you're clear to write. If not, sleep or something and loop until it's clear. Then set the variable indicating you're writing, write the file, set the variable saying it's clear.  Static variable is shared across all threads, so it will work in the scope of one web server

Comment: the folder is blocked till I'll turn off IIS server ... I'm seeing this in development enviroment I hope in production enviroment it can't happen ...

Comment: I've never seen that...